# inet_addr()という関数でエラーがでる

Tags: c++, delphi, rad-studio

現在、RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。
Indy9のコンポーネントで作成されたものをIndy10に置き換えています。
ServerConnectメソッドで次のところでエラーが出てきました。

このエラーの回避方法を教えて下さい。

```cpp
void __fastcall TfrmMain::ServerConnect(TIdContext *AContext)

//-----(中略)--------------------------

pDev = AddDev(pPkt,inet_addr(AContext->Connection->Socket->Binding->PeerIP.c_str()));

//-----(中略)--------------------------

}
```

**エラー内容**

```
[bcc32c エラー] Main.cpp(566): no matching function for call to 'inet_addr'
  winsock2.h(1831): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'wchar_t *' to 'const char *' for 1st argument
```

Comment: `rad-studio` のようなツールのタグは、そのツールの「使い方」等に関連した質問の際に割り当ててください。単にそのツールを使っているというだけで付けるのは、あまり良いタグ付けではありません。 / 質問内容としては C++ か Delphi、Indy などの方がより適切じゃないでしょうか。

Comment: 指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

修正しました。

```cpp
char ch[xx];  // xxは文字列が入る大きさ以上の値
strcpy(ch, AnsiString(AContext->Connection->Socket->Binding->PeerIP).c_str());
pDev = AddDev(pPkt,inet_addr(ch));
```

でどうでしょう？

Comment: コピー先(`ch`)はポインタではなく配列等のメモリ領域である必要があると思います。いかがでしょうか?

Comment: そうですね、これではメモリーを壊してしまいます。char* ch = "";はchar ch[xx]とすべきでした。xxは文字列が入る十分なサイズで。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。適当なんですが ch[128] としてビルド成功しました。

Comment: @nordsynth 動的に確保してもよろしいのではないかと。`std::string peer = AnsiString(...);` としておいて `char *ch = new char[peer.size()+1];` 使い終わったら `delete[] ch;`

Comment: ありがとうございます。newとか使ってみたいので活用させて頂きます。

Answer (score 0):

ここの記事の内容が同様に当てはまるのでは？ `AnsiString`に変換するのが簡単そうですね。
だから@池田茂樹 さん回答のように1段階処理を挟むか、下記記事のようにインラインで変換するかすれば良いのでは？

[C++Builder2009におけるStringの変更による既存コードの修正](https://www.gesource.jp/weblog/?p=543)

> C++Builder2007まではコンパイルできた次のコードが、C++Builder2009ではコンパイルエラーになります。
>
> ```
> String dir = "C:\\日本語.txt";
> FILE* f = fopen(dir.c_str(), "rt");
>
> [BCC32 エラー] File1.cpp(14): E2034 'wchar_t *' 型は 'const char *' 型に変換できない
> [BCC32 エラー] File1.cpp(14): E2342 パラメータ '__path' は const char * 型として定義されているので wchar_t * は渡せない
> ```
>
> **StringがAnsiStringからUnicodeStringに変わったため、String#c_str()の返す型がchar*からwchar_t*に変わりました。**
>   fopenには引数にchar*を受け取るfopen(char*)はありますが、wchar_t*を受け取るfopen(wchar_t*)は存在せず、C++Builder2009ではコンパイルエラーになります。
>   **C++Builder2009でも一度AnsiStringに変換するか、_wfopenを使えば、コンパイル可能です。**
>
> ```
> # AnsiStringに変換
> FILE* f = fopen(AnsiString(dir).c_str(), "rt");
>
> # _wfopenを使用
> FILE* f = _wfopen(dir.c_str(), L"rt");
> ```

---

以下の記事の例を考えれば、`inet_addr`に渡すパラメータの型が合っていないのでしょう。

[No matching function for call to エラー 原因別の対処方法](https://marycore.jp/prog/cpp/no-matching-function-for-call-to/)

> これは関数呼び出しが正常に行えないという趣旨のメッセージで、原因はいくつか考えられる。
>   関数
>   引数の型が一致しないケース
>   引数型が合っていないと呼び出せないのでエラーになる。
>
> ```
> void fn(int v) {}
>
> fn(99); // OK
> fn(""); // No matching function for call to 'fn'
> ```
>
> 関数側の定義をきちんと確認せよ。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。詳細なサイト紹介ありがとうございます。活用させて頂きます。