# GetPrivateProfileString関数でエラー

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

現在、RAD Studio 10.3でプログラミングを行っています。

```cpp
char Buf[256];
---------------(中略)---------------------
GetPrivateProfileString("LANG_JPN","TOOLBAR_SERVER_STOP","Stop",Buf,40,".\\Japan.ini");
```

exeファイルと同じフォルダにあるJapan.iniファイルから文字データを取り出そうとしているようなのですが、次のようなエラーが発生します。

```
[bcc32c エラー] Main.cpp(1383): no matching function for call to 'GetPrivateProfileStringW'
  winbase.h(4417): candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR' (aka 'const wchar_t *') for 1st argument
```

このエラーの回避方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: この辺の記事の内容では？ [_TCHAR のマッピング](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/TCHAR_%E3%83%9E%E3%83%83%E3%83%94%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0), [C++ アプリケーションの Unicode 対応](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/C%2B%2B_%E3%82%A2%E3%83%97%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B1%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE_Unicode_%E5%AF%BE%E5%BF%9C), [RAD Studio における Unicode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/ja/RAD_Studio_%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B_Unicode)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Win32 API の使用経験はありますか？
`GetPrivateProfileString` という API 関数は、実は存在しません。
`GetPrivateProfileString` は、実際には下記のどっちか片方の別名となっています。
`GetPrivateProfileStringA` という `ANSI` 版 (`char` 系を引数に受け取る) 
`GetPrivateProfileStringW` という `WideChar` 版 (`wchar_t` 系を引数に受け取る)

Visual Studio 等では、プロジェクトのオプションでどっちを使うかを切り分けています。オイラが使ったことのない RAD Studio でも同等のはず。んで、今のエラーメッセージからすると、あなたのプロジェクトは `UNICODE` 設定 (`WideChar` 側を使う) になっているようです。

なぜこんな複雑怪奇な仕様になっているかというと Win95 系と WinNT 系で Win32 API の実装が異なっていたという事情があるのですが、もう既に Win95 系が絶滅している関係で新しく作るソフトで `ANSI` 版を使う理由は何一つなく、ゆえにプロジェクトのデフォルト値は `UNICODE` 設定となっています。（`A` 系は多国語対応できないしエンコード変換が入るので遅い）

RAD Studio でどうかは知りませんので以下は Visual Studio の場合ですが

1. `_TCHAR` を使い `ANSI` / `WideChar` 両方に対応したコードにする

`char` 型ではなく `_TCHAR` 型を使い、かつ文字列リテラルは `_T("...")` とする
`#include <tchar.h>` が必要

```
_TCHAR buf[40];
GetPrivateProfileString(_T("LANG_JPN"), _T("TOOLBAR_SERVER_STOP"), ... );
```

`ANSI` ビルドすると Win95 用 EXE が作れ（日本語オンリー) `UNICODE` ビルドすると WinNT 用 EXE が作れ多国語対応になります。

2. `WideChar` 限定とする

`char` 型ではなく `wchar_t` 型を使い、かつ文字列リテラルは `L"..."` とする
明示的に `W` 版 Win32 API を呼ぶ
こちらの場合 `#include <tchar.h>` は不要

```
wchar_t buf[40];
GetPrivateProfileStringW(L"LANG_JPN", L"TOOLBAR_SERVER_STOP", ... );
```

これだと多国語対応が自動でできてしまいます。が Win95 には非対応となります。

3. プロジェクトの設定を `ANSI` に変えちゃう

今のソースコードを変えなくていいはず。その代わり多国語対応はできません（日本語 Windows を使うと中国語やタイ語を使うことはできなくなる）

4. `ANSI` API を明示的に使う

プロジェクトの設定は `UNICODE` のままで明示的に `ANSI` 版 API 関数を使ってもいいです。デメリットは 3. に同じ。

```
char buf[40];
GetPrivateProfileStringA("LANG_JPN", "TOOLBAR_SERVER_STOP", ... );
```

移植前ソースコードが `FILE* f=fopen(filename, "rb");` のようにバリバリに `char` 型を使っているなら 3. か 4. のほうが書き換え量は少ないですが、いまどき流ではないっすね。日本語限定がとても痛いっす。かといっていきなり `WideChar` 版に全部直すのも困難かもしれないし、どっちにするかはお任せします。

Comment: 詳細な回答頂きありがとうございます。助かります。”GetPrivateProfileStringA”のみで済む修正でやってみました。

Comment: 多言語対応に関する方法もありがとうございます。活用させて頂きます。

Answer (score 6):

質問者さんの一連の質問を読む限り、ご自身で書かれたコードではなく他人の書かれたコードを移植していると理解しました。
他人の書いたコードをANSI / Unicode変換するのは危険です。タグ指定されているC++言語とはあまり関係なく、RAD Studio側だと思いますが、元通りANSIでビルドされることをおすすめします。

- [inet_addr()という関数でエラーがでる](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/60953/4236)
- [GetPrivateProfileString関数でエラー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/61092/4236)

などは、ANSI / Unicodeを切り替えたことによって発生しているコンパイルエラーですが、このようにエラーが発生してくれる場合はまだいいのですが、

```
void* memcpy( void *dest, const void *src, size_t count );
```

`memecpy`などのように`void*`が使われてしまうと、本来ANSI文字列が必要とされている箇所がUnicodeに切り替わっていてもコンパイラーは検出できず、実行時に不可解な現象が発生します。こういったコード上で見えない問題を回避するためにもANSIでビルドすべきです。

最近あった例で[「Windows 10」のシャットダウンを妨げる謎の「G」アプリ、マイクロソフトが説明](https://japan.zdnet.com/article/35145860/)では

```
L"GDI+ Hook Window"
```

というUnicode文字列をANSI APIに渡してしまったがために`"G"`と解釈されてしまう現象を引き起こしています。

Comment: RadStudio自体が10.3だとライブラリがユニコードに変わっているので、この上でANSIでビルドするのはそれはそれで色々不具合が出そうな気がします。ANSIでビルドするならC++Builder2007を使うのが良いかと思いますが製品版を購入しないと入手出来ません

Comment: @au2010 なるほどそういう事情があるんですね。まあその辺りも含めてツール選びするしかないですね。

Comment: 回答頂きありがとうございます。活用させて頂きます。